# When should I use a class and when should I use a id?

Tags: html, css

When should I use a class and when should I use an id in html for styling my page.

Example: `<h1 class="ClassName">`
         `<h1 id="IDName">`

Comment: There are several existing questions about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [id vs class declarations in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973459/id-vs-class-declarations-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs are unique, whereas classes can be reused. You could also use both simultaneously:

```
<h1 class="ClassName" id="IDName">
```

As a general rule of thumb, use id's as individual identifiers, and classes for common markup that you intend to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You use `id` if you have only one element of a kind and `class` if you have many.

For example you have a list:

```
<div class="listItem">Item 1</div>
<div class="listItem" id="selected">Item 2</div>
<div class="listItem">Item 3</div>
```

Here you can get the selected element using javascript: `document.getElementById('selected')`.

You should never have the same `id` twice but you should always have a `class` many times.

Also have a look at [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), it explains it very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Use id to identify elements that there will only be a single instance of on a page or single div . For instance, if you have a single navigation bar that you are placing in a specific location, use `id="navi"`., for header `used id="header_sectoin"`, for any used function in jquery than used to id `id="slider_left"`

Use class to group elements that all behave a certain way. For instance, if you want your company name to appear in bold in body text, you might use .

Example:

Text

```
#header_section {font-color:#fff}
.header_section {font-color:#000}
```

The text would be white.

For details :

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

id is unique. For example if you want to assign a css style only to one of the tags you cand relate them with id. class can be reused. for example if you want to assign a css style to all of the `<a>` tags you must use class.

Answer (score 0):

ID's are unique
Each element can have only one ID
Each page can have only one element with that ID

Classes are NOT unique
You can use the same class on multiple elements.
You can use multiple classes on the same element.

There are no browser defaults for any ID or Class
Adding a class name or ID to an element does nothing to that element by default.

Elements can have BOTH